# How to get substring up until first two consecutive capital letters (but not including those two letters)

Tags: php

How to get substring up until first two consecutive capital letters?

An example is: `"test message HERE I am";`

For which I would want "`test message`"

Comment: http://php.net/substr http://php.net/preg_match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use regexp for this:

```
$str = 'test message HERE I am';
echo trim(preg_replace('~([A-Z]{2,}.*)~', '', $str)); // test message
```